# Insert record to 3 columns from left to right

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, loops

What is the best way to make that construction, i have many record with people names, and i need to put them all to 3 strips column, beetween each column huge space, and all names can be arbitrary length, for example

```
 |Bob|         |Jonh|         |Victor|
|Sergej|      |Kennedi|       |Mark|
|Antuan|      |Kristina|      |Cryst|
```

I need to put them all to that colums in loop automaticaly, and one after the other,

```
|1|  |2|  |3|
|4|  |5|  |6|
|7|  |8|  |9|
```

Maybe somebody can advice me how it will be better to do, now i create 3 `<ul>` and in each `ul` i have some `<li>`, but that way will display my record one under the other. And if i use ul i need to get count all record, divide it to 3, and then put in each ul some record, maybe there is better way ?

Comment: If it's tabular data, use a table. Also [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) might be of some use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fabien pointed out, if its tabular data, then you can format it inside a table and use `array_chunk()` to group them by three's. Consider this example:

```
<?php

$names = array(
    'Bob',
    'John',
    'Victor',
    'Sergej',
    'Kennedi',
    'Mark',
    'Antuan',
    'Kristina',
    'Cryst',
);

$names = array_chunk($names, 3); // group them by three's

?>

<table border="0" cellpadding="10">
    <?php foreach($names as $key => $value): ?> 
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($value as $index => $element): ?> 
            <td><?php echo $element; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </tr>       
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```